# Move onmouseover images to the left?

Tags: css, html, onmouseover

Here is my page: http://www.ostmoconstruction.com/portfolio.php

I have decided to change the image onmouseover for each of the images in this small gallery to give a larger preview of images, but when I provide more images more the center and right image, they go outside of the div. Is there anyway to move the middle paragraph to the left onmouseover or something along those lines to keep the whole thing in the div layer?

Is there any way to, when the image changes on the mouseover, move it to the left-hand side of the div layer - to effectively keep it from going outside of the(right side) div layer?

Comment: Sorry. Is there any way to, when the image changes on the mouseover, move it to the left-hand side of the div layer - to effectively keep it from going outside of the(right side) div layer?

Comment: i don't see no image changing with my firefox on ubuntu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The other answer was almost correct, but I also had to wrap it in a div that had "position: relative;" with it's own negative left-margin. This pushed the other image and it's title outside of view!

You can see the results here: http://www.ostmoconstruction.com/portfolio.php

Answer (score 0):

Add this styling to the image that shows up on mouseover

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 38px;
```

Comment: I would really like this to work, but the way it is currently set up, when the image expands, it pushes the other images out of the div which is what we want because then the title is repositioned in the center and none of the titles overlap, but when you set the positioning to absolute, the images (and now titles) end up on top of each other.

Comment: Maybe if I could just make the other divs disappear?