# Align right and push paragraph outside of the div layer

Tags: html, image, cell, css-tables

Here is my page: http://www.ostmoconstruction.com/portfolio.php

If I hover over the first image in each row, the resulting image is the full size of the div and therefore, pushes the second image outside of visibility.

I would like the same thing to happen when I hover over the second image. Perhaps it would push the first image outside the left side of the div layer and display only the second image. I tried setting the positioning to absolute onhover and left: 0; and this seemed to work, but also seemed unstable and left the title of the first image in tact (sometimes conflicting with the title of the second).

Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up solving the problem in this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329533/move-onmouseover-images-to-the-left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making the image's position absolute and wrapping it in a relatively positioned div layer then gave both negative left margins to align then correctly. The absolute positioning allowed my to bring it to the left and the relative positioning allowed my to push the other image outside of the container div. More info here: [Move onmouseover images to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329533/move-onmouseover-images-to-the-left)

Answer (score 0):

I have the one solution **Conflicting Title** you can try :

```
p a {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    }
```

Comment: That's kind of the direction I ended up going. I took a screenshot of the background and put it behind the title when it moved, but in order to get the onmouseover to quit glitching from moving over so much, I had to put a very long(to the right) background(same color as the page background) behind the image, but that forced the title over to the right of the picture (the new center of the image), so to get it back I had to put it in a span and give it a negative left margin. As you can see if you go back to that page, that puts the title off-centered when the larger image is visible.

Comment: Not perfect, but that works - if anyone has a better solution, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Hopefully all of that made sense